# HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When i go to central administration i get this error

Service Unavailable

---

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

but my site are working that i have created

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check the application pool for your central admin site (this can be done with IIS manager).

It is possible that the app pool is in stopped state (due to some error or a service account password expiration, etc.). In this case you may need to restart the app pool.

If the app pool is working fine, you may need to check the SharePoint logs to get more details on your problem.